# Analytic continuation of $f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n (z-e^{2\pi i r_n})}$

Tags: complex-analysis, uniform-convergence, analytic-continuation, holomorph

> Let $\{r_k:k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ be a counting set of rational numbers in $[0,1]$. Show that $$f(z) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^k (z-e^{2\pi i r_k})}$$ is holomorphic on $U_1=\{z\in \mathbb{C} : |z| < 1\}$ and $U_2 = \{z\in \mathbb{C} : |z|>1\}$. Are both functions analytic continuations from each other?

I've already learned that if $(f_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a compactly convergent sequence of holomorphic functions and $f$ its limit, then $f$ is also holomorphic.

Taking $$f_n(z) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{2^k (z-e^{2\pi i r_k})}$$
it would make sense that it's enough to prove that this series is uniformly convergent on $U_1, U_2$.

For $k\in \mathbb{N}$: $\frac{1}{2^k(z-e^{2\pi i r_k})}$ is holomorphic because we know that $\frac{1}{z-\exp(2\pi ir_k)}$ is holomorphic in $z\in \mathbb{C}\setminus \{\exp(2\pi i r_k)\}$ and $\exp(2\pi i r_k)$ is neither in $U_1$ nor in $U_2$ $\forall k$.

Let $z\in U_1$ and $R = \inf\{|z-\exp(2\pi i r_k)|: k\in \mathbb{N}\}$:

\begin{align*}
|f_n(z)-f(z)| = |\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^k(z-e^{2\pi i r_k})}| \leq \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^k|(z-e^{2\pi i r_k})|} \leq \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^k R} \overset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0
\end{align*}

Analogous with $z\in U_2$ and $R = \inf\{|z-\exp(2\pi i r_k)|: k\in \mathbb{N}\}$.

With that I should have proven that $f(z)$ is holomorphic on $U_1$ and $U_2$, right?

Now to my main question: What does "are both functions analytic continuations from each other" mean in this context? $U_1\cap U_2 = \emptyset$ and they're essentially the same function, so yes?

Comment: The answer is no in the strict sense since they have no relationship one with another - analytic continuation requires domains with non empty intersection; here most likely they are not pseudo analytic continuation either as I do not see boundary limits from either side, but for that I would have to look it up, plus there are various ways of defining pseudo analytic continuations

Comment: @Conrad In lecture we defined "direct analytic continuation" where we also needed $U_1 \cap U_2 \neq \emptyset$. I thought there is another definition for "normal" analytic continuation. But I'll ask the prof again, so no need to look it up! :)

Do you think my proof regarding $f$ is holomorphic on $U_1$, $U_2$ is correct?

Comment: Proofs look almost correct except that you need to prove uniform convergence on compacts not absolute convergence at a point, but the main point is that if $|z|<1$ its distance to the boundary, hence to the singularities is bounded below by $R$ and that holds true for $z\in K$ compact in the unit disc since any such compact is included in some disc of radius $r<1$ so you can take $R=1-r$; then the proof goes exactly as you did and same for the outside

Comment: @Quotenbanane hey, ich vermute mal das du auch kompl. analysis übungen  beim grabner machst. ich sehe keine möglichkeit, dir persönlich zu schreiben, deshalb melde ich mich hier. bist mit aufgab 46 vielleicht weiter gekommen?

Comment: @syphracos Hi, nö sorry, ich brauch nur noch 1 Beispiel und hab mir 46 gar nicht angeschaut :(

Comment: @Quotenbanane kein Problem. Danke trotzdem! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\{r_k,k\ge 1\}$ is a dense subset of $[0,1]$ then $f(z)=\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{2^{-k}}{z-e^{2i\pi r_k}}$ is analytic for $|z|<1$ and it has a **natural boundary** on $|z|=1$.

This is because for $x\in [0,1)$, $\sum_{k\ge 1,|e^{2i\pi r_k}-e^{2i\pi r_l}|\ge \epsilon} \frac{2^{-k}}{x e^{2i\pi r_l }-e^{2i\pi r_k}}$ is bounded while $\lim_{x\to 1^-} 
\Re(\sum_{k\ge 1, |e^{2i\pi r_k}-e^{2i\pi r_l}|< \epsilon} \frac{2^{-k}}{e^{2i\pi (r_k-r_l)}-x})\ge \frac{2^{-k}}{1-x}
=+\infty$

So $f(z)$ isn't continuous at $e^{2i\pi r_l}$.

Comment: what about $|z| >1$ ?

Comment: @syphracos what do you mean? the functions on $|z|<1$ and $|z|>1$ are unrelated in term of analytic continuation as there is a natural boundary separating the two.

Comment: sorry, I misinterpreted your proof. I thought it was regarding $f$ being holomorphic on $U_1$ and $U_2$

Comment: how do you get from $xe^{2\pi i r_l} - e^{2\pi i r_k}$ to $e^{2 \pi i (r_k - r_l)} - x$?

Comment: @syphracos I think he just divided the left term by $-e^{2\pi i r_l}$